# I made an input tag in html but I dont know how to save the user input

Tags: html

So basically I created an input tag but without the form tag because whenever I put the form tag that has the action that link to another html page in it, it just go into that html page. I want the user to input like "Exit" and so they will back out to the first page. I have to use the input tag instead of the button.

Comment: Can you show the html? helping you will be easier

Comment: You're going to need a lot more than just html to achieve this. Are you using jquery or another javascript package in your site?
As an aside, this probably isn't a great user interface design either.

Answer (score 0):

You can remain the form tag. For the submit event, to prevent redirecting to the link of the action, you can simply use javascript/jQuery with event.preventDefault(), and then do your thing after the code.